# Find corner, Unity 3D

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, graphics, algebra

I'm trying to find the right place to put 2 wall corners, I mean, when I join 2 cubes I need to find the proper lace between them to move the corner vertices, see

[image]

[image]

[image: enter description here]

**and this what I want to achieve**
[image]

Any one know a way to do it? Fill the empty space in the corner, betwen the union of the 2 cubes

Comment: It is not clear what are your initial data - size and position of rectangles? And what you want - move them to coincide external corners? Calculate and fill two triangles from black quadrilateral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a purely theoretical level I would check the distance between the global position of one of the pairs of vertices and move them to the center coordinates of this new vector.

i.e: Say that the position of outerVertice1 = (2,3) and outerVertice2 = (3,4), you can use the midpoint formula to get the point between them: ((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2), which in this case:

5/2,7/2 = (2.5;3.5)

If you now move both vertices to this point and do the same with the inner vertices, they would hopefully merge the two polygons in the desired way.

Answer (score 0):

I just have founded the interpilatedt rotation (.5) betwen 2 nodes or corners, then just use the vector intersection formula to find where put the vert.

Thanks for the interest :)